# How to get vSphere host name rather than host id?

Tags: php, soap, vmware

I have a script (below) which connects to a vCenter and pulls off all of the VMs and what host they are currently on. The only thing is it only gives me the host ID not the name. Is there any way to get the name as well or lookup the name after it has got the id?

```
<?php
class soapclientd extends soapclient
    {
        public $action = false;
        public function __construct($wsdl, $options = array())
            {
                parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
            }
        public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
            {
                $resp = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
                return $resp;
            }
    }
$client = new SoapClient("https://192.168.1.103/sdk/vimService.wsdl", array("trace" => 1, "location"=>"https://192.168.1.103/sdk"));
try
    {
        $request = new stdClass();
        $request->_this = array ('_' => 'ServiceInstance', 'type' => 'ServiceInstance');
        $response = $client->__soapCall('RetrieveServiceContent', array((array)$request));
    } 
catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
$ret = $response->returnval;
try
    {
        $request = new stdClass();
        $request->_this = $ret->sessionManager;
        $request->userName = 'root';
        $request->password = 'vmware';
        $response = $client->__soapCall('Login', array((array)$request));
    } 
catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
$ss1 = new soapvar(array ('name' => 'FolderTraversalSpec'), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'selectSet', null);
$ss2 = new soapvar(array ('name' => 'DataCenterVMTraversalSpec'), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'selectSet', null);
$a = array ('name' => 'FolderTraversalSpec', 'type' => 'Folder', 'path' => 'childEntity', 'skip' => false, $ss1, $ss2);
$ss = new soapvar(array ('name' => 'FolderTraversalSpec'), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, null, null, 'selectSet', null);
$b = array ('name' => 'DataCenterVMTraversalSpec', 'type' => 'Datacenter', 'path' => 'vmFolder', 'skip' => false, $ss);
$res = null;
try
    {
        $request = new stdClass();
        $request->_this = $ret->propertyCollector;
        $request->specSet = array (
            'propSet' => array (
                array ('type' => 'VirtualMachine', 'all' => 0, 'pathSet' => array ('name','runtime.powerState', 'config.hardware.numCPU', 'config.hardware.memoryMB', 'runtime.host')),
            ),
            'objectSet' => array (
                'obj' => $ret->rootFolder,
                'skip' => false,
                'selectSet' => array (
                    new soapvar($a, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'TraversalSpec'),
                    new soapvar($b, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'TraversalSpec'),
                    ),
                )
            );
        $res = $client->__soapCall('RetrieveProperties', array((array)$request));
    } 
catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
$tvCPU = 0;
$tvRAM = 0;
echo "<table><tr><td width='450px'>Name</td>    <td width='100px'>vRAM (MB)</td><td width='100px'>vCPU</td><td width='100px'>Power State</td><td width='100px'>Host</td> </tr>";
$arrlength=count($res ->returnval);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) 
    {
        $name = $res -> returnval[$x] -> propSet[2]->val;
        $vRam = $res -> returnval[$x] -> propSet[0]->val;
        $vCPU = $res -> returnval[$x] -> propSet[1]->val;
        $pState = $res -> returnval[$x] -> propSet[4]->val;
        $host = $res -> returnval[$x] -> propSet[3]->val->_;
        echo "<tr><td width='450px'>".$name.
        "</td><td>".$vRam.
        "</td><td>".$vCPU.
        "</td> <td>".$pState.
        "</td> <td>".$host.
        "</td></tr>";
        $tvCPU = $tvCPU + $vCPU; 
        $tvRAM = $tvRAM + $vRam; 
    }
echo "<tr><td width='450px'>Total VMs - ".$x."</td><td>". $tvRAM."</td><td>". $tvCPU."</td></tr>";
?>
```